# Missing files when publishing using folder profile in VS 2019

Tags: directory, publish, visual-studio-2019, precompile, not-exists

When I publish a new web app (started in VS 2019) to a folder on the intranet (using a "folder profile"), not all files are published.

If I don't use the pre-compile option, I don't get any publish errors, but files are missing when I access the website on the server. If I do use the pre-compile option, the publish fails with the following message:

"Error The file '/Logout.aspx.vb' does not exist."

The aspx file header looks like this:
    <%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Logout.aspx.vb" Inherits="Logout" %>

I tried using the following for the CodeFile:

```
Logout.aspx.vb  
~/Logout.aspx.vb
./Logout.aspx.vb
```

all with the same results.

I've selected "Delete all files prior to publish" and "Precompile during publishing" (with default configuration).

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Follow-up: I found I could configure the publish to include "All files in this project" instead of "Only files needed to run this application", and all files would be published. Not sure why I need to do this, as the original (default) option of "Only files needed to run this application" is what I should be using.